# Dragging object onto container and flagging as occupied

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have multiple objects and multiple containers, My plan is that any object can be dropped on any container, but once a container has an object dropped on it, I want it to be occupied and not allow any more objects on to it. Is there an isOcuppied call or something like that, I cant find any examples of this.

```
    local function onTouch( event )
local t = event.target

local phase = event.phase
if "began" == phase then
    -- Make target the top-most object
    local parent = t.parent
    parent:insert( t )
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )


    -- Spurious events can be sent to the target, e.g. the user presses 
    -- elsewhere on the screen and then moves the finger over the target.
    -- To prevent this, we add this flag. Only when it's true will "move"
    -- events be sent to the target.
    t.isFocus = true

    -- Store initial position
    t.x0 = event.x - t.x
    t.y0 = event.y - t.y
elseif t.isFocus then
    if "moved" == phase then
        -- Make object move (we subtract t.x0,t.y0 so that moves are
        -- relative to initial grab point, rather than object "snapping").
        t.xScale = 1.7
        t.yScale = 1.7
        t.x = event.x - t.x0
        t.y = event.y - t.y0
        --t1 = t1..t.value
    elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
    for i = 1, #posX do
     if (((t.x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX[i] - ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY - ((1/3) * sizeY))) and (t.x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX[i] + ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY + ((1/3) * sizeY)))) or ((t.x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX[i] - ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY - ((2/3) * sizeY))) and (t.x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX[i] + ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY + ((2/3) * sizeY)))) or ((t.x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX[i] - ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (t.y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY - ((1/2) * sizeY))) and (t.x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX[i] + ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (t.y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY + ((1/2) * sizeY))))) then
        t.x, t.y = posX[i] + (sizeX/2), posY + (sizeY/2);
     elseif  (((t.x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1[i] - ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/3) * sizeY))) and (t.x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1[i] + ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/3) * sizeY)))) or ((t.x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1[i] - ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((2/3) * sizeY))) and (t.x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1[i] + ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((2/3) * sizeY)))) or ((t.x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1[i] - ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (t.y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/2) * sizeY))) and (t.x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1[i] + ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (t.y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/2) * sizeY))))) then
        t.x, t.y = posX1[i] + (sizeX/2), posY1 + (sizeY/2);
        t2[i] = t.value
        --t1 = t1..t.value
     -- elseif  (((t.x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX2 - ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY2 - ((1/3) * sizeY))) and (t.x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX2 + ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY2 + ((1/3) * sizeY)))) or ((t.x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX2 - ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY2 - ((2/3) * sizeY))) and (t.x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX2 + ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (t.y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY2 + ((2/3) * sizeY)))) or ((t.x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX2 - ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (t.y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY2 - ((1/2) * sizeY))) and (t.x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX2 + ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (t.y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY2 + ((1/2) * sizeY))))) then
        -- t.x, t.y = posX2 + (sizeX/2), posY2 + (sizeY/2);
    end
    end
        t1 = t1..t.value
        t.xScale = 1
        t.yScale = 1
        --print(tile.label)
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
        t.isFocus = false
        --n = n + 1
        --value = " "
    end
end
```

Here is my code as it stands, Also Im I have a value attached to each tile e.g tile a = "A", currently I'm just appending a string each time a tile is moved, but I want the string or maybe use a table to only be appended when the tile has been put in a container. For example if one letter is in the wrong place and I move it to the right place I have touched it twice so my final string will be wrong

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this problem? I have got it reading the word or phrase correctly, all I need now is how to stop a tile from going on top of another in the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set a value on your container:

```
myContainer.isOccupied = false
```

Then in your event handler, when every you get to your ended phase you can simply do a check:

```
if not myContainer.isOccupied then
    -- code to drop
    myContainer.isOccupied = true
end
```